# How to iterate over values of a previous target in drake

Tags: r, drake-r-package

In drake, I want to take the *values* of one target and use them in a `map` to create more targets. In the example below, is there a way to make `y2` actually be three targets, as it does for `y3`? I know it's very different to have the actual values than a target that will be evaluated later, so maybe this is impossible.

```r
x_vals = as.numeric(seq_len(3))

add_1 <- function(x) {
  print(length(x))
  x + 1
}

plan <- drake::drake_plan(
  x1 = x_vals,
  # Runs, as expected, on the whole vector at once
  y1 = add_1(x1),
  # Runs on the whole vector, despite the map()
  y2 = target(add_1(z), transform=map(z=x1)),
  # Makes three separate targets, runs the function on each element
  y3 = target(add_1(z), transform=map(z=!!x_vals))
)
drake::make(plan)
#> target x1
#> target y3_1
#> [1] 1
#> target y3_2
#> [1] 1
#> target y3_3
#> [1] 1
#> target y1
#> [1] 3
#> target y2_x1
#> [1] 3
```

My question is closely related to this one, but I want to use the new `map` interface:
[How to refer to previous targets in drake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842037/how-to-refer-to-previous-targets-in-drake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`drake`](https://github.com/ropensci/drake) requires that you explicitly declare all your targets in advance before you run `make()`. So unfortunately, the functionality you propose is not currently available. Many others have requested it, and it is [part of `drake`'s future development goals](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/685). However, it is the biggest implementation challenge to date, and I have no idea when it will become available. `map()` and friends may be a step closer.